# R - Gráficos com informações de diferentes colunas

Tags: r, tabela-html, gráfico

Olá,

Estou com o seguinte problema: preciso criar uma tabela e um gráfico com informações sobre nível escolaridade para diferentes cargos da firma para diferentes anos e regiões.

Tenho 4 níveis de escolaridade (fundinc, medioinc, superiorinc e supdout) e 3 níveis de cargos (apoio, operacional e estrategico).

Cada nível de escolaridade e cada cargo é uma coluna (se fundinc == 1, as demais são 0, se apoio == 1, operacional e estrategico são 0).

Exemplo:

```
fundinc | medioinc | superiorinc | supdout | apoio | operacional | estrategico
1       | 0        | 0           | 0       | 1     | 0           | 0
0       | 1        | 0           | 0       | 0     | 1           | 0
0       | 0        | 1           | 0       | 0     | 0           | 1
0       | 0        | 1           | 0       | 0     | 0           | 1
0       | 1        | 0           | 0       | 1     | 0           | 0
1       | 0        | 0           | 0       | 1     | 0           | 0
.
. 
.
```

As bases de dados estão separadas por ano e região (data2010nordeste, data2010norte, ..., data2016sudeste, data2016sul).

**   Alguma sugestão de como fazer isso? Estou completamente perdido.

*** Eu quero ver qual o nível de escolaridade de cada cargo, por exemplo, quantos "fundinc", "medioinc", etc, estão no cargo "apoio" e outros. Eu não sei qual gráfico pode apresentar isso melhor, talvez um barplot comum.

Tentei criar uma função

```
pegaescolaridadeapoio = function (base) {

  #Fundamental incompleto

  a <- base[base$fundinc==1 & base$apoio==1, ]

  #Medio incompleto

  b <- base[base$medioinc==1 & base$apoio==1,]

  #Superior incompleto

  c <- base[base$superiorinc==1 & base$apoio==1,]

  #superior e outros

  d <- base[base$supdout==1 & base$apoio==1,]

  vetor <- c(nrow(a),nrow(b),nrow(c),nrow(d))

  return (vetor)
}
```

Após isso, tentei criar uns vetores e colocá-los em tabelas, mas sem sucesso.

Grato desde já.

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow Brasil! Infelizmente, esta pergunta não pode ser reproduzida por quem for tentar respondê-la. Por favor, [dê uma olhada neste link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/824/como-criar-um-exemplo-m%c3%adnimo-reproduz%c3%advel-em-r) e veja como fazer uma pergunta reproduzível em R. Assim, as pessoas que desejarem te ajudar conseguirão fazer isto da melhor maneira possível.

Comment: @MarcusNunes tentei editar para deixar mais compreensível. Infelizmente sou iniciante e acho que não fiz nada mais útil que isso :(

Comment: A melhor maneira de compartilhar dados do `R` é através do comando `dput`. [Este link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/824/como-criar-um-exemplo-m%c3%adnimo-reproduz%c3%advel-em-r) mostra como fazer isto. Compartilhar uma parte dos dados desta maneira é a melhor forma de garantir que os outros usuários do site vão te ajudar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por primeiro você irá precisar arrumar o seu conjunto de dados, de forma que você tenha apenas 2 colunas:

```
base2 <- read.csv2("base2.csv") # Base de dados do seu exemplo
nova.base <- data.frame(Escolaridade = names(base2[1:4])[max.col(base2[1:4])],
                        Cargo = names(base2[5:7])[max.col(base2[5:7])])
```

Tabela simples:

```
with(nova.base, table(Escolaridade, Cargo))
             Cargo
Escolaridade  apoio estrategico operacional
  fundinc         2           0           0
  medioinc        1           0           1
  superiorinc     0           2           0
```

Gráfico simples:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(nova.base, aes(x = Escolaridade, fill = Cargo)) +
  geom_bar()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]